# React typescript error Parsing error: '>' expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I am migrating js to ts and have an error with my modified code:

Line 26:8:  Parsing error: '>' expected

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect, RouteProps } from "react-router-dom";
import {render} from "react-dom"
import {AppProps} from "../App"

function querystring(name: string, url = window.location.href) {
  name = name.replace(/[[]]/g, "\\$&");

  const regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)", "i");
  const results = regex.exec(url);

  if (!results) {
    return null;
  }
  if (!results[2]) {
    return "";
  }

  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
export default function UnauthenticatedRoute({ component: C, appProps, ...rest }:
                                                 RouteProps & {appProps: AppProps}) {
  const redirect = querystring("redirect");
  return (
    <Route
        {...rest} // the issue is here
        render={ props => !appProps.isAuthenticated ?
            <C {...props} {...appProps} />
          :
            <Redirect to={redirect === "" || redirect === null ? "/" : redirect}/>
    }
    />
  );
}
```

If someone sees the problem, that would be kind :). Thanks!

---

## Solution

1/ File needs to have tsx extension

2/ syntax was also wrong in the tsx syntax. I changed to this and now it's ok:

```
export default function UnauthenticatedRoute({ component: C, appProps, ...rest }:
                                                 RouteProps & {appProps: AppProps}) {
  const redirect = querystring("redirect");
  return (
    <Route {...rest}
        render={ props => !appProps.isAuthenticated ?
            <C {...props} {...appProps} />
          :
            <Redirect to={redirect === "" || redirect === null ? "/" : redirect}/>
        }
    />
  );
}
```

Now I have another issue with binding element 'C', but it's another story.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This is a `*.tsx` formatted file. Probably it's sufficient to change the file extension.

Comment: @Andreas_D That's what I did. Same error.

Comment: @KevinB You mean arount {...rest}? Not working.

Comment: No, i meant the arrow function. then realized it's an entirely different line. but i still think it's in some way relevant to the problem

Comment: I still think that tsc tries to compile that and fails, because it's no valid typescript  code and that it's a configuration issue. You could try cloning a react-typescript boilerplate project and compare how they did it there.

Comment: @Andreas_D yes there was an isssue with the syntax but just by changing spacing and next line, it got fixed. Don't know the exact syntax issue though. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Change the file extension from `.ts` to `.tsx`.

Comment: ok I changed to tsx and changed a bit the spacing around the tsx returned and it worked.

Comment: I... I was trying so hard yesterday to troubleshoot this. I didn't realize it was this simple.

Answer (score 2):

extension must be: .TSX  NOT .ts

if the file extension is already  .tsx, then you need to Restart your app, cause in Cache memory, the extension is still .ts

just restart or rebuild the app.

if it is: Create React App, then do this in terminal:

- ctrl + c
- npm start

should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Just take note: when returning react-dom, always use TSX otherwise TS